# sql server compact edition Data editor

Tags: sql-server-ce

Is there any gui/tool which allows you to edit the data in the ssce db file ??

like the sql server management studio which allows you to the select a table in sql express+ and edit-add/update/delete the data in that table using a grid interface !

Comment: found the answer, you can edit via visual studio server explorer
pls ignore this question or let me know how to delete/withdraw this

thanks

Answer (score 5):

As you mentioned in your comment, you can edit the table data via the Server Explorer in Visual Studio.

Just add a new connection to the .sdf file, expand the Tables view, right-click on the table you want to edit, and select "Show Table Data".

This will bring up a grid view you can edit.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

http://dukelupus.wordpress.com/2008/10/28/sql-ce-database-editor-v2-beta/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it seems like it should be pretty easy to develop your own SQL editor and include the required Compact Edition .dlls into the project and then you wouldnt have to use Visual Studio any more.  Why hasn't anyone done this?   Is there a reason I am overlooking of why it might not be possible?

Answer (score 0):

mskfisher's Server Explorer suggestion worked for me in VS 2010, but I wasn't able to get it to work in 2013.  I could not get the CE Provider to show up in the list when I tried to Add Connection for some reason.

Instead, I ended up using the SQL Server Compact Toolbox add-in found [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e313dfd-be80-4afb-b5e9-6e74d369f7a1).  I'm able to use it both for VS 2010 and 2013 and it works like a charm.